# Web fonts only working on Chrome and Safari for Mac,

Tags: html, css, fonts

the designer send me some fonts to use on a website. Here is my fonts.css file:

```css
/* Delicious */

/* Delicious Bold */

@font-face{ 
    font-family: 'delicious';
    src: url('fonts/delicious-bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/delicious-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/delicious-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/delicious-bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/delicious-bold-webfont.svg#webfont') format('svg');
}
```

But apparently this only work on my Mac but only on Chrome and Safari, does anybody see an error o have some advice to solve this issues, because on a linux or windows this doesn't work no matter if you are using chrome, safari, IE, opera o whatever.

Thanks for your help guys.

UPDATE

---

Line on the css file:

```css
font-family: 'delicious', Arial, sans-serif;
```

Comment: you missed the dash in delicous-heavy, delicous-italic and delicous-small, may be making your delicous font not work

Comment: Can you show the CSS you are using to actually use the font as well, please. e.g. `#something { font-family: Delicious-BoldItalic; }`

Comment: @Blowski thanks for your help. I just update the question, with the information you asked.

Comment: @Pete actually I'm only use the first one

Comment: Can you use the browser's development tools to see if the file is actually being included. In Chrome right-click, `Inspect Element` -> `Network`. You should see the font-files being included somewhere. My guess is that either the path to the fonts is wrong, or the protocol is blocking access to them in some browsers.

Comment: I'm getting 404 GET on every font :S

Comment: @Blowski thanks man, I have a problem with the route of the fonts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the browser's development tools to see if the file is actually being included.

In Chrome right-click, <kbd>Inspect Element</kbd> -> <kbd>Network</kbd>. You should see the font-files being included somewhere. My guess is that either the path to the fonts is wrong, or the protocol is blocking access to them in some browsers